# lock a page/form using $animate. angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spinner, interceptor, ng-animate

I need to create a form locker with progress bar or spinner dynamically  . 
https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/blob/master/src/loading-bar.css has the code for the spinner but it just displays the spinner and not locking the form..

Is there any way to lock the form page once the spinner is loaded so that no more actions are done .

start the spinner

```
 this.parentSelector = 'body';
 var $parentSelector = this.parentSelector,
var $parent = $document.find($parentSelector);
                spinner = angular.element('<div id="loading-bar-spinner"><div  class="spinner-icon"></div></div>');



{
$animate.enter(spinner, $parent);
}
```

css :

```
#loading-bar-spinner {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: 350ms linear all;
  -moz-transition: 350ms linear all;
  -o-transition: 350ms linear all;
  transition: 350ms linear all;
}

#loading-bar.ng-enter,
#loading-bar.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
#loading-bar-spinner.ng-enter,
#loading-bar-spinner.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

#loading-bar.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
#loading-bar.ng-leave,
#loading-bar-spinner.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
#loading-bar-spinner.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

#loading-bar-spinner {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10002;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;


}

#loading-bar-spinner .spinner-icon {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;

  border:  solid 22px yellow;
  border-top-color:  #29d;
  border-left-color: #29d;
  border-radius: 120px;

  -webkit-animation: loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:    loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:     loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation:      loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  animation:         loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend using open-source on those components.
I have good experience with [blockUI](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui).

Features:

- You can add your own spinner.
- You can decide to run the spinner on each server call(by default) or you can control it youself.
- It's super simple to integrate\config as a module.